# Split <input type="file" multiple> into various inputs or set separate name for every file for Shopify line item properties

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file, shopify

I'm struggling to give users convenient interface to upload files when making their orders on our Shopify store. Shopify has this functionality of product line item properties (scarcely documented in [Shopify dev docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/templates/product#line-item-properties) and in community forums [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/cart-use-cart-attributes-to-collect-more-information/m-p/613718) and [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/product-pages-get-customization-information-for-products/m-p/616525)).

The following proof-of-concept HTML (prepared based on documentation above), when placed inside the product form, gives the desired result on Shopify admin end, but doesn't provide good user experience, making users to pick files one by one.

```
<input type="file" name="properties[upload1]">
<input type="file" name="properties[upload2]">
<input type="file" name="properties[upload3]">
```

[image]

Shopify doesn't give access to server-side code for processing file uploads, and I'm looking for a way to provide users with

1. ability to select multiple files at once
2. (optionally) remove files one by one

– but with native Shopify functionality, without building an app like [Live Product Options](https://apps.shopify.com/live-product-options) (which uploads images to their servers and feeds URLs as text to Shopify, see example [here](https://custominflatables.co/collections/custom-products/products/custom-round-lounger-inflatable)).
So I wonder if some of the following is possible:

1. Splitting files specified to a single `<input type="file" multiple>` attribute into multiple separate inputs.
2. Make files specified to `<input type="file" name="some_magic_array_name" multiple>` be processed as if they had different names specified to each of them individually like name="properties[upload1]", name="properties[upload2]", etc.

Any ideas are welcome. After all the research I've done, I'm almost convinced it's not doable, but decided to ask for public opinion.
Thanks for reading this.

UPD: I'm open to implementing it both as asynchronous JavaScript or simple HTML form. See below my current code for add to cart asynchronously:

```
if (!customElements.get('product-form')) {
  customElements.define('product-form', class ProductForm extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.form = this.querySelector('form');
      this.form.querySelector('[name=id]').disabled = false;
      this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this));
      this.cart = document.querySelector('cart-notification') || document.querySelector('cart-drawer');
      this.submitButton = this.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
      if (document.querySelector('cart-drawer')) this.submitButton.setAttribute('aria-haspopup', 'dialog');

      this.hideErrors = this.dataset.hideErrors === 'true';
    }

    onSubmitHandler(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      if (this.submitButton.getAttribute('aria-disabled') === 'true') return;

      this.handleErrorMessage();

      this.submitButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
      this.submitButton.classList.add('loading');
      this.querySelector('.loading-overlay__spinner').classList.remove('hidden');

      const config = fetchConfig('javascript');
      config.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
      delete config.headers['Content-Type'];

      const formData = new FormData(this.form);
      if (this.cart) {
        formData.append('sections', this.cart.getSectionsToRender().map((section) => section.id));
        formData.append('sections_url', window.location.pathname);
        this.cart.setActiveElement(document.activeElement);
      }
    
      //Added to generate selling plan add to cart response
      const sellingPlanId = window.getCurrentSellingPlanId();
      formData.append("selling_plan", sellingPlanId);
      
      config.body = formData;

      fetch(`${routes.cart_add_url}`, config)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status) {
            publish(PUB_SUB_EVENTS.cartError, {source: 'product-form', productVariantId: formData.get('id'), errors: response.description, message: response.message});
            this.handleErrorMessage(response.description);

            const soldOutMessage = this.submitButton.querySelector('.sold-out-message');
            if (!soldOutMessage) return;
            this.submitButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
            this.submitButton.querySelector('span').classList.add('hidden');
            soldOutMessage.classList.remove('hidden');
            this.error = true;
            return;
          } else if (!this.cart) {
            window.location = window.routes.cart_url;
            return;
          }

          if (!this.error) publish(PUB_SUB_EVENTS.cartUpdate, {source: 'product-form', productVariantId: formData.get('id')});
          this.error = false;
          const quickAddModal = this.closest('quick-add-modal');
          if (quickAddModal) {
            document.body.addEventListener('modalClosed', () => {
              setTimeout(() => { this.cart.renderContents(response) });
            }, { once: true });
            quickAddModal.hide(true);
          } else {
            this.cart.renderContents(response);
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.submitButton.classList.remove('loading');
          if (this.cart && this.cart.classList.contains('is-empty')) this.cart.classList.remove('is-empty');
          if (!this.error) this.submitButton.removeAttribute('aria-disabled');
          this.querySelector('.loading-overlay__spinner').classList.add('hidden');
        });
    }

    handleErrorMessage(errorMessage = false) {
      if (this.hideErrors) return;

      this.errorMessageWrapper = this.errorMessageWrapper || this.querySelector('.product-form__error-message-wrapper');
      if (!this.errorMessageWrapper) return;
      this.errorMessage = this.errorMessage || this.errorMessageWrapper.querySelector('.product-form__error-message');

      this.errorMessageWrapper.toggleAttribute('hidden', !errorMessage);

      if (errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage.textContent = errorMessage;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are the requests made asynchronously using JavaScript or is it just a standard HTML form submit? Please [edit] your question to include any relevant code

Comment: @Phil, thanks for your interest. I'm open to implement it either way. Included my current code for asynchronous add to cart to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely doable.

I got a rough version working. But it's slow with larger files and I'm using jQuery. It can be converted to javascript but this is just to get you in the right direction.

You could probably add a loading so they know to wait before submitting. You can also show the files as images on the side cart instead of the raw image file.

Put the below in your form:

```
 <input type="file" id="files-upload" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"> <div class="filesx"></div>
```

Script Not sure why it's breaking it apart.

```
    window.onload = function () {
```

$('#files-upload').change(function() {

```
[].forEach.call(this.files, function(file, index){
    
     var reader = new FileReader();
   
   reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
    
        console.log(theFile);
      
      // Render the image.
      var inputx = document.createElement('div');
      inputx.name = 'properties[file'+index+']';
      inputx.innerHTML = '<input hidden value="'+e.target.result+'" name="properties[file'+index+']">';
       $(".filesx").append(inputx);
    };
  })(file);
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
});
```

});
}